# Discord Bot that generates random food recipe's using Spoonacular api

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord, spoonacular

I am trying to make a discord bot in Nextcord Python that will generate a random recipe using a $randomrecipe command.
I tried making it so that it would send a title of a dish (and also the image and ingredients) but I cant get it to work.

```
@bot.command(name='randomrecipe')
async def randomrecipe(ctx):
    r = requests.get('https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=apikey')
    title_name = r.json() ["title"]
    await ctx.send(title_name)
```

here's the error for that code

```
Ignoring exception in command randomrecipe:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iliaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 168, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\iliaa\Downloads\json\app.py", line 22, in randomrecipe
    title_name = r.json() ["title"]
KeyError: 'title'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iliaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1048, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\iliaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 933, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iliaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 177, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'title'
```

Comment: What happens when you visit that url in your browser? Can you edit the output of that into your question? I don't have a key for that api.

Comment: What are you trying to send to the client? The response is a long json with a bunch of names, peroperties, and cooking instructions.

Comment: I'm trying to send the dish title and image. In JSON title is labeled as title and image is labeled like this "image":"https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/636812-556x370.jpg

Comment: Try `title_name = r.json() ["recipes"][0]["title"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means, that the api not returned a title.
The issue lies in following line: `title_name = r.json()["title"]`
Try to print put r.json() without the ["title"] `print(r.json())`
You will notice, that title key is not included in the response.
You are looking for title in the root element but after reproducing it, printing out the whole response, i noticed that title is located inside recipes. There are multiplie title keys and because you want the title of the dish (which is the first one) you need to index it by 0 (computers start couting at 0) so you should try to use `r.json()["recipes"][0]["title"]`
After using it this way, i got follwoing output:
`All Day Simple Slow-Cooker FALL OFF the BONE Ribs`

Here the full code i've used:

```py
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=your_key_here')
print(r.json()["recipes"][0]["title"])
```

Comment: Someone already answered this question a while ago in the question comments but thanks anyway!